# Connection timeout in server

Tags: c#, connection-pooling, connection-timeout

I want to ask about connection timeout since I have a problem with it.
The error is

> "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occured because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

Can code like this cause a connection to timeout?
What is best practice to call connection??

```
using (var cnn = OpenExternalContractor()) //call connection string
{
    var query = @"insert into interfaceRequest  (requestNo,requestAssemblyName,requestApplicationName,requestFunctionName,
            requestParameters,requestUserName,requestUserMail,requestDate)
            values (@requestNo,@requestAssemblyName,@requestApplicationName,@requestFunctionName,
            @requestParameters,@requestUserName,@requestUserMail,getDate())";
                cnn.Execute(query, new
                {
                    requestNo = requestNo,
                    requestAssemblyName = requestAssemblyName,
                    requestApplicationName = jobName.Split('-')[0],
                    requestFunctionName = jobName.Split('-')[1],
                    requestParameters = requestParameters,
                    requestUserName = requestUserName.Replace("\"", "\\"),
                    requestUserMail = userMail
                });
                //Call another function here that call connection string
                PersonnelRepository.UpdateLastNumber(requestNamePrefix,   Convert.ToInt32(lastNumber));
}

public static void UpdateLastNumber(string type, int value)
{
    using (var cnn = OpenExternalContractor()) //Call connection string
    {
        var query = "update AutoNumber set LastNumber = " + value + " where Type = '" + type + "'";
        cnn.Query<int>(query);
    }
}
```

Here are the code for connection string:

```
protected static IDbConnection OpenExternalContractor() 
{
    IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExternalContractor"].ConnectionString);
    dbConnection.Open();
    return dbConnection;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I would use a `SqlCommand` instead of using the Connection. You can then set the `Timeout` for the command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is this  error normal ?? Maybe it is caused by connection leak?? If I specify the timeout,  will this error occurred again in the future ??

Comment: Depending on how long the query takes to execute.  The default timeout is 30 seconds.  You can amend it in your `ConnectionString`.

Comment: Thanx, I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

When getting the string of your connection by using `WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExternalContractor"].ConnectionString`, you can change in your `WebConfig` file the connection timeout by altering this connection string like this for example :

```
Data Source=(local);
Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
Connection Timeout=30
```

From [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8c87fb8-2ef2-429f-af52-20e9e0074357/changing-default-connection-timeout-value-for-sql-connection?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Is it enough by specify Connection Timeout or is it ecause of connection leak in my code??

Comment: Generally we let the default timeout because it is enough, but if you know your server will take more time to bring back the connection you can specify a more larger timeout.

Comment: Ok, I will try it today, I hope it run well, Thnx